# Sharepoint 2016 Events 6398 and 6306 Repeating Application Pool stopped

Tags: iis

SharePoint 2016 Farm 2 Nodes Front End And Application
Windows 2019 Data Center Servers

I have a problem on my SharePoint Services I am getting many event Error 8306  No one can logon to the sites

I checked the .NET and it is set to FULL 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/security/event-id-8306-and-cannot-activate-security-token-service-application    per this article I found.

The SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool continues to stop  I restart it and it stops immediately    here are the events

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          5/5/2020 11:20:48 AM
Event ID:      6398
Task Category: Timer
Level:         Critical
Keywords:
User:          network\spfarm
Computer:      SERV027-N1..network.com
Description:
The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsageImportJobDefinition (ID 5855313d-025b-4407-96e2-7e9b2edba8d2) threw an exception. More information is included below.

Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS' is denied.. (Correlation=9b794f9f-8839-e0f1-3ea7-bb55bf6ffaf9)
Event Xml:

  
    
    6398
    16
    1
    12
    0
    0x2000000000000000
    
    78039
    
    
    Application
    SERV027-N1.network.com
    
  
  
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsageImportJobDefinition
    5855313d-025b-4407-96e2-7e9b2edba8d2
    Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS' is denied.. (Correlation=9b794f9f-8839-e0f1-3ea7-bb55bf6ffaf9)

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          5/5/2020 11:20:13 AM
Event ID:      8306
Task Category: Claims Authentication
Level:         Error
Keywords:
User:          network\spfarm
Computer:     SERV027-N1.network.com
Description:
An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The HTTP service located at http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later..
Event Xml:

  
    
    8306
    16
    2
    47
    0
    0x2000000000000000
    
    78038
    
    
    Application
    SERV027-N1.network.com
    
  
  
    The HTTP service located at http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later.

Any ideas or suggestions

Comment: To resolve the access denied errors, run `Initialize-SPResourceSecurity` on each server.

Comment: Trevor thank you for responding so quickly  I ran Initialize-SPResourceSecurity on both Nodes then started the apppoll but it stopped right away still   Do I need to do anything after running that command?

Comment: got it working now monitoring it for next 24 hours    the account on the application pool need to be added to Logon as a Batch right on the server now the application pool is staying started